# whats wrong in this mysql code

Tags: php, mysql

whats wrong here????

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc from materials' at line 1

this is the code

```
<?php
$serverName ="localhost";
$dbname="inventory";
$conn = mysql_connect($serverName,"root","");
if(!$conn) die("Connection error". mysql_connect_error());
else echo "connected successfully";
$desc = mysql_query("select desc from materials where code = 123",$conn ) or  die (mysql_error());
mysql_close($conn); ?>
```

Comment: add a `back-tick` you have a column named `desc`.  "select \`desc\` from materials where code = 123"

Comment: `desc` is a reserved word, basically because it is the keyword in a sort `order by x desc` so as you have picked a reserved word for this column name you have 2 options. 1) the prefered oprion, use another name for this column and 2) wrap the column name is backticks `select \`desc\` from materials where code = 123`

Comment: The third option is to qualify the reference to the column name with the tablename or table alias. For example: **`select materials.desc from materials where`**

Answer (score 1):

You are using reserved words, so need to escape.

```
select `desc` from materials where code = 123
```

> Certain objects within MySQL, including database, table, index,
>   column, alias, view, stored procedure, partition, tablespace, and
>   other object names are known as identifiers. This section describes
>   the permissible syntax for identifiers in MySQL. [Section 9.2.2,
>   “Identifier Case Sensitivity”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html), describes which types of identifiers
>   are case sensitive and under what conditions.

The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;
```

> An identifier may be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains
>   special characters or is a reserved word, you must quote it whenever
>   you refer to it. (Exception: A reserved word that follows a period in
>   a qualified name must be an identifier, so it need not be quoted.)
>   Reserved words are listed at [Section 9.3, “Keywords and Reserved](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)
>   Words”.

**It is recommended not to use reserved words.**

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you have not selected any database for performing queries. Add this line for selecting database after 6th line:

> else echo "connected successfully";

```
$dbconn = mysql_select_db( $dbname , $conn);
if (!$db_conn) {
   die ('Can\'t use this database: ' . $dbname . mysql_error());
}
$desc = mysql_query("select `desc` from materials where code = 123",$conn ) or  die (mysql_error());
//desc is a reserved keyword in mysql, so you ought to put it between the ` symbol
```

Comment: what're you mixing `mysqli_` and `mysql_` for?